# Linear transformations that send basis vectors to the same images

Tags: linear-algebra

In my book it says as a passing remark to finish off a problem: "...two linear transformations that send basis vectors to the same images must be equal...".

I'm wondering if this is a definition or some result that would have a proof. If the latter, can someone provide a sketch of the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis. If $T(v_i)=0$ for all $i$ then $T=0.$ Why? For any $v\in V$ there exist $a_1,\dots, a_n$ such that $v=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n.$ Then

$$Tv=T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)=a_1Tv_1+\dots+a_nTv_n=0.$$

Now assume that $R(v_i)=S(v_i)$ for any $i.$ Consider $T=R-S.$ What can you conclude?

Comment: don't you mean " If $T(v_i)=0$ for *all* i then $T=0$"?

Comment: Also nowhere have you made assumptions that lead to $v$ being in the kernel. This answer doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @WilsonBrians Yes, I mean for all. Who has assumed $v$ is in the kernel? I have shown it must be in the kernel if $T(v_i)=0$ for all $i.$

Comment: you should write "*Assume* $T(v_i) = 0$ for all $i$. Not "if".

Comment: @WilsonBrians What's the problem with the sentence "If ... then ..."?

Comment: it's just confusing here because the "if" statement corresponds to your conclusion that $T = 0$.

Comment: Let me disagree. The statement is $T(v_i)=0$ and the thesis is $T=0.$